# Generating a Lookup Table

Tags: java

What's the best way to represent a "lookup" table in Java using properties file:

Say I have this **lookup.properties** file with: (*although I think using a properties file is very wrong for this case*)

```
(0,999)=/mnt/partition0/
(1000,1999)=/mnt/partition1/
(2000,2999)=/mnt/partition2/
(3000,3999)=/mnt/partition3/
(4000,4999)=/mnt/partition4/
(5000,5999)=/mnt/partition5/
(6000,6999)=/mnt/partition6/
(7000,7999)=/mnt/partition7/
```

And a method

```
String id = "2001";
String partition = getPartitionPathById(id);
// returns /mnt/partition2/
```

Comment: You can try a hashmap.

Comment: Create a custom class to hold the id range and the partition path.  Your getPartitionPathById method would be a method of the custom class.  You can put the instances of the custom class in a List, since you only have 8 ranges.

Comment: I would recommend to have such configurations as json object in a central place, like Database to be like : key array of json low, high and value as path. This will enable you to dynamically change it with no limitations. Also reading json object will not take time as you are handling ranges already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
public class PartitionImpl implements Partition {

  NavigableMap<Range, String> map;

  public PartitionImpl() {

  }

  @Override public String getPartition(Application application) {
    return getPartition(application.getAppId());
  }

  @Override public String getPartition(String appId) {
    if(map == null) {
      map = new TreeMap<Range, String>();
    }
    map.put(new Range(0, 999), "/mnt/partition0/");
    map.put(new Range(1000, 1999), "/mnt/partition1/");
    map.put(new Range(2000, 2999), "/mnt/partition2/");
    map.put(new Range(3000, 3999), "/mnt/partition3/");
    map.put(new Range(4000, 4999), "/mnt/partition4/");
    map.put(new Range(5000, 5999), "/mnt/partition4/");
    map.put(new Range(6000, 6999), "/mnt/partition6/");
    map.put(new Range(7000, 7999), "/mnt/partition7/");

    String idPart = appId.split("-")[1]; // return an integer value
    Integer id = Integer.valueOf(idPart);
    AtomicReference<String> thePartition = new AtomicReference<>();
    map.entrySet().forEach(rangeStringEntry -> {
      String partition = rangeStringEntry.getValue();
      Range range = rangeStringEntry.getKey();
      if(range.upper >= id && range.lower <= id) {
        thePartition.set(partition);
      }
    });
    return thePartition.get();
  }

}
```

```
public class Range implements Comparable<Range> {
  public int lower, upper;
  public int value;

  public Range(int lower, int upper) {
    this.lower = lower;
    this.upper = upper;
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(@NotNull Range range) {
    if (range.lower == this.lower && range.upper == this.upper) {
      return 0;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```